# Como funciona o lock do C#?

Tags: c#, .net, thread, concorrência

Estava dando uma olhada num artigo da [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), mas não ficou bem claro o porque de usar isso.

```
class Account
{
    decimal balance;
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            if (amount > balance)
            {
                throw new Exception("Insufficient funds");
            }
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`Lock` é uma ferramenta muito útil quando você precisa garantir acesso exclusivo a um dado recurso, ou garantir *Thread safety*.

Essa função faz uso de um objeto como sinalizador de sincronização (no seu exemplo, o objeto `thislock`).

No código de exemplo, a primeira *thread* a executar o método `Withdraw` irá obter o `lock` do objeto `thislock`, e executará o bloco de código. Qualquer outra thread que tentar executar a mesma instância do método irá entrar em *WaitState* (ou *estado de espera*) caso encontrem a instrução `lock` e outra *thread* possua o direito de acesso.

Uma fila é criada, e as *threads* em espera irão receber a liberação do lock em estilo FIFO (*First In, First Out*).

Answer (score 20):

Para complementar, o `lock` é uma espécie de semáforo. De fato, através dele é possível implantar uma estrutura de dados capaz de controlar o tráfego de processamento que é chamada de [semáforo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).

O `lock` liga uma luz vermelha dizendo para qualquer código que tente acessar aquele trecho de memória que está proibido de fazer até que a luz se apague. Note que embora pareça um semáforo, não o é de fato. Por isto o `lock` em si pode **ser usado** em um semáforo que é uma estrutura um pouco mais sofisticada.

Ele indica para toda a aplicação que naquele momento alguma coisa será feita com o objeto que não pode ser interrompida. Que nenhuma parte da aplicação pode considerar o estado do objeto enquanto ele não for liberado porque a operação naquele momento pode estar inconsistente ou incompleta.

Quando seu código for compilado o *statement* `lock` se torna um código equivalente a este:

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = thisLock;
try {
    Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken);
    if (amount > balance) {
        throw new Exception("Insufficient funds");
    }
    balance -= amount;
} finally {
    if (lockWasTaken) {
        Monitor.Exit(temp); 
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/LockSource.cs).

Note que é possível obter o mesmo resultado usando apenas a biblioteca mas não é recomendado.

Em códigos que você tem certeza que nunca terá *threads* você não precisa e não deve usar este tipo de sincronismo. Para algumas operações o custo de performance da execução dos métodos da classe [`Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) pode ser proibitivo.

Veja o [Reference Source do .NET para entender o funcionamento interno da classe](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Monitor.cs,1bfe37ac9214200c) (não que ajude muito :D).

Comment: +1, excelente menção à estrutura de semáforos.

Answer (score 5):

Vale pesquisar sobre concorrência de recursos. O semáforo por exemplo pode ser utilizado quando você tem um pool de recursos (por exemplo 3 conexões ativas) e precisa garantir que nenhum seja utilizado por mais de um consumidor.