# Keyword para C# equivalente a "synchronized" do Java

Tags: c#, .net, sincronização, singleton, thread-safety

#### Problema

Estou implementando um gerenciador de conexões que implementa o padrão [Singleton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton), gerenciando um *pool* de conexões com chaves únicas para cada nova conexão. Então estou tento problemas com a paralelismo do meu gerenciador, pois o mesmo pode ser chamado por varias *threads*, o que causa erros de tentava de duplicidade de conexão com a mesma chave.

#### Exemplo:

Gostaria de algo em C# similar a isto em Java:

```
synchronized(instances) // ou synchronized no método
{
    if (!instances.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        // ... create connection
        instances.Add(key, /* add connection */);
    }
    return instances.get(key);
}
```

#### Pergunta

- Qual seria forma equivalente `synchronized` do Java para C#? (pode ser para método ou para bloco de código)
- Como essa forma funciona? Como devo utilizá-la? Quais as diferenças em relação a `synchronized` do Java?

> Gostaria de uma breve explicação da solução equivalente em C#!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em C# usa-se o [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) só para blocos de código. Essencialmente é só trocar a palavra-chave. Há equivalência semântica.

```
lock (instances) {
    if (!instances.ContainsKey(key)) {
        // ... create connection
        instances.Add(key, /* add connection */);
    }
    return instances[key];
```

Nesse exemplo pode ser mais interessante usar um [`TryAdd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryadd?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_TryAdd__0__1_). Ou talvez usar um dicionário concorrente, como mostra o exemplo na página da documentação *linkada* desse método.

Em C# ele é apenas açúcar sintático, então este código:

```
lock (lockObject) {
    DoSomething();
}
```

se transforma neste:

```
object obj = (System.Object)lockObject;
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(obj);
try {
    DoSomething();
} finally {
    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(obj);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/Lock.cs).

Para métodos precisa usar um atributo: [`MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)`](https://dolearncs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

Há uma [implementação concorrente de Singleton na documentação da Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650316(v=pandp.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Jon Skeet escreveu sobre isso também](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

[Pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28690/101).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta bigown! Só para entender, se no caso eu utilizar `ConcurrentDictionary` e utilizar o método `TryAdd()` para adicionar os elementos no `ConcurrentDictionary`, seria redundante e desnecessário (para o meu caso) a utilização de `lock` para evitar o paralelismo de acesso ao bloco de código, já que pelo que entendi o `TryAdd()` já faz esse trabalho. Correto?

Comment: Eu acredito que sim. Claro que não vi todo o contexto, nem sei se é a melhor abordagem.

Comment: Ok, obrigado novamente. Realmente acho que [`ConcurrentDictionar‌​y`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) aparentemente funciona como mencionei no comentário anterior, como é possível entender no comentário de descrição da `class`: **"Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently."**, que traduzido de forma livre seria: **"Representa uma coleção thread-safe de pares chave/valor que pode ser acessado por múltiplos threads simultaneamente."**

Comment: Sim, é que eu entendo também.

Answer (score 2):

Fernando, pelo que pude entender sobre o "synchronized" ele protege o código para que só uma thread possa acessá-lo por vez, em C# o equivalente é o "lock". ex.:

```
static object _locker = new object();
...
public static void MeuMetodo()
{
  lock(_locker)
  {
    //meu código
  }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Éderson! Sua resposta está correta e funciona perfeitamente para o meu caso (pelo menos em meus testes, hehe), só marquei como resposta a do bigown pois acabei utilizando uma das alternativas ([`ConcurrentDictionary` `TryAdd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291(v=vs.110).aspx)) que ele citou em sua resposta que para o meu caso pareceu ser mais adequada (até onde testei também). (Já está contabilizado ai meu +1 =D).