# Como acessar objeto criado por outra thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

É possível acessar um objeto criado por outra *thread*?

Comment: Sim, é. Da mesma forma que acessa um objeto criado na mesma *thread*. A única coisa que deve se observar é que se o objeto for mutável pode criar problemas se o acesso for concorrente e precisa de cuidados especiais e talvez travamento, o que pode inviabilizar seu uso. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Você acessa da mesma forma que acessa um objeto criado na mesma *thread*. Não existe diferenciação entre objetos criados na mesma *thread* ou em outra. Pelo menos quando estamos falando de [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Não existe nada especial a ser feito.

A função da *thread* é justamente [permitir mais de uma linha de processamento e um ambiente de memória único para toda aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101).

Se o objeto estiver no *stack* pode ser um problema tentar acessá-lo como referência em algumas situações porque ele pode nem existir mais. Mas em geral objetos no *stack* são copiados para outro método independente deste método estar rodando em outra *thread*, então apesar de ter o mesmo valor passa ser outro objeto. É muito fácil trabalhar com esses objetos porque eles se tornam independentes e em *threads* diferentes cada um estará em seu próprio *stack*. É o caso de todos os [tipos por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). Mas também não tem que fazer nada especial para acessar os objetos do *stack*, desde que acesse o objeto do próprio *stack*. Se você não usa um [`ref`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101) em um objeto por valor é garantido que que está no mesmo *stack* já que haverá uma cópia.

Objeto [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) também são fáceis de lidar porque é garantido que ele nunca será alterado. Se precisar do objeto com um estado diferente precisa criar outro objeto. Um exemplo é a [`string`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3711/101).

Se o objeto for mutável pode criar problemas se o acesso for [concorrente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101) e aí precisa de cuidados especiais e talvez [travamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28690/101), o que pode até inviabilizar seu uso e ficar mais lento do que sem o uso de *thread*. Veja [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101).

Tem [otimizações possíveis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397N&view=net-5.0) mas que raramente são necessárias.

Quase sempre preferirá usar [`Task` e não `Thread`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101).

Veja mais em [Qual a diferença entre os async, multithreading, paralelismo e concorrência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Caro bigown, obrigado pela aula. Mas (acho que eu não elaborei a pergunta direito), você não deu exemplo de como fazer em C#, pois estou recebendo um "exceção" do depurador ao tentar acessar o objeto de outra thread. (não há problemas de concorrência)

Comment: @Paulo de fato sua pergunta não fala nada disto, pode fazer outra pergunta colocando o código relevante e qual o erro.

Comment: Não é um erro. De fato estou acessando um objeto criado por outra thread, e o depurador do Visual Studio está indicando isso como operação inválida. Queria saber como resolvo.

Comment: Ou seja, é um erro. Tem que postar tudo o que te falei, sem isso não temos como adivinhar.

Comment: Ok. Vou tentar ser mais específico.

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar um objeto de outra thread, é necessário dar o `Invoke`.

O jeito mais fácil de dar um `Invoke` é:

### Exemplos

**Dentro do seu Windows Form:**

```
this.Invoke(new Action(()=>{ /* TODO: Seu código aqui */ }));
```

**Em um componente de tela:**

```
button1.Invoke(new Action(()=>{ /* TODO: Seu código aqui */ }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar objetos criados em outras Threads, porém deve tomar cuidado para não acessar o mesmo objeto de duas Threads simultaneamente a menos que a documentação deste objeto diga que é seguro fazer isso (thread safe).

Porém existem casos em que não se pode fazer isso, e isso não é coisa do C# em si, nem mesmo do Windows, que é acessar a UI de uma thread que não foi a que a criou.

É bem comum você ouvir falar de `UI Thread`, que é a thread responsável por tudo que acontece na UI do programa e só ela deve modificar a UI.

O erro que você diz que o Visual Studio está te dando é bem comum neste caso, de se estar tentando modificar a UI do Windows Forms de outra Thread.

Na verdade isto nem mesmo é um erro, isso é uma verificação extra que o Visual Studio ativa em modo Debug, isso é feito através do `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`, ele sempre vai ser `true` quando se está debugando, se executar o programa sem estar debugando este valor vai ser `false` e ele não deve disparar a Exception.

Só que você nunca deve modificar este valor, eu geralmente digo se você alterar este valor você só vai esconder um bug em seu código que vai ser muito difícil de ser detectado.

Mas o motivo do Visual Studio modificar esta propriedade em tempo de debug é basicamente para o Visual Studio poder te dizer "Olha, você não devia estar fazendo isso", e ele faz isso pois o comportamento da UI quando modificada fora da thread que a criou não é definido, pode acontecer qualquer coisa.

Já vi um caso de uma pessoa que preencheu um DataGridView por outra Thread e no PC dele funcionou, mas quando ia para produção o DataGridView não mostrava nada, ele nem renderizava corretamente, apareciam apenas partes dos cabeçalhos sem texto nenhum, e é isso que é o comportamento não definido, hora ele pode funcionar, hora não, e não existe um padrão para isso, não tem como corrigir isso pois não é um bug em si, o bug está em usar o controle de outra thread.