# Como travar um método para que outros não chamem enquanto ele é usado?

Tags: c#, .net, thread, multithreading

Tenho um simples método de `log`, que adiciona algumas linhas para um arquivo especial.

O problema é que, o aplicativo é multi-threading, e em cada Thread é chamado este método para fazer o log, e quando um é chamado, ele trava e abre o arquivo somente para aquela instância onde o método foi chamado, e se o outro Thread chamar, é atirado o erro dizendo que o arquivo já está sendo usado.

Vamos explicar com o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima, **Thread 1** chamou o método `Log` ao mesmo tempo que o **Thread 2** chamou, e o que aconteceu? `Log` não soube lidar com os dois chamando ao mesmo tempo e meio que "dividiu os logs", criando duas instâncias do mesmo método, assim, apenas um `Log` poderá escrever no arquivo, e o outro irá atirar um erro já que o arquivo já está sendo usado.

O corpo do método `Log` é o seguinte:

```
    public enum LogType
    {
        Errr = 0,
        Warn = 1,
        Info = 2
    }

    public static void Log(LogType typ, string str)
    {
        string k = string.Format("{0,-8} {1,-15} {4,4} {5,7} {2,4} : {3}", "Program", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), typ.ToString(), str, DateTime.Now.Millisecond, pid);

        string path = GetAppData() + "\\" + "log.txt";
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write(k.ToString() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Pode ser facilmente chamado em qualquer lugar do código.

Como resolvo isso? Existe maneiras de contornar ou travar este método para que outras chamadas "aguardem" a finalização dele e evitem congestionamento do arquivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem veja a documentação [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement). Já tem uma resposta sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28692/43340).

```
public class SuaClasse
{
    private readonly object balanceLock = new object();
    public static void Log(LogType typ, string str)
    {
        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            string k = string.Format("{0,-8} {1,-15} {4,4} {5,7} {2,4} : {3}", "Program", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), typ.ToString(), str, DateTime.Now.Millisecond, pid);

            string path = GetAppData() + "\\" + "log.txt";
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(k.ToString() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```